# A lightweight CRUD, based on the Table Data Gateway pattern

Tags: php, database, crud

In order to reduce the boilerplate code, I decided to write a lightweight database helper, based on the  [Table Data Gateway pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) (or at least the way I understand it) with the aim of using it for a simple CRUD application.

Writing INSERT and UPDATE queries is always a nuisance, repeating all those ranks of column names, parameter names, binding parameters and such. So I decided to write a simple class that does all the job under the hood, and accepts/returns simple arrays, without going down the rabbit hole of creating a full featured ORM.

My aim was also to make this class as secure as possible, hence the table and field names are always hardcoded.

It consists of one prototype class,

```
abstract class BasicTableGateway
{
    protected $db;
    protected $table;
    protected $fields;
    protected $primary = 'id';

    public function __construct(\PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function listBySQL(string $sql, array $params): array
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
    public function list(int $page = 1, int $limit = 50): array
    {
        $page--;
        $offset = $page * $limit;
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$this->table` LIMIT ?,?");
        $stmt->execute([$offset,$limit]);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
    public function read($id): ?array
    {
        $ret = $this->listBySQL("SELECT * FROM `$this->table` WHERE `$this->primary`=?", [$id]);
        return $ret ? reset($ret) : null;
    }
    public function update(array $data, int $id): void
    {
        $this->validate($data);

        $params = [];
        $set = "";
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $set .= "`$key` = ?,";
            $params[] = $value;
        }
        $set = rtrim($set, ",");
        $params[] = $id;
        $sql = "UPDATE `$this->table` SET $set WHERE `$this->primary`=?";
        $this->db->prepare($sql)->execute($params);
    }
    public function insert($data): int
    {
        $this->validate($data);

        $fields = '`'.implode("`,`", array_keys($data)).'`';
        $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($data) - 1) . '?';

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->table` ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)";
        $this->db->prepare($sql)->execute(array_values($data));

        return $this->db->lastInsertId();

    }
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `$this->table` WHERE `$this->primary`=?";
        $this->db->prepare($sql)->execute([$id]);
    }
    protected function validate($data)
    {
        $diff = array_diff(array_keys($data), $this->fields);
        if ($diff) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unknown field(s): ". implode($diff));
        }
    }
}
```

and children classes where related properties are set to operate certain tables:

```
class UserGateway extends BasicTableGateway {
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fields = ['email', 'password', 'name', 'birthday'];
}
```

which is then used like this

```
$data = [
    'email' => 'foo@bar.com',
    'password' => 'hash',
    'name' => 'Fooster',
];
$id = $userGateway->insert($data);
$user = $userGateway->read($id);
echo json_encode($user),PHP_EOL;

$userGateway->update(['name' => 'Wooster'], $id);
$user = $userGateway->read($id);
echo json_encode($user),PHP_EOL;

$users = $userGateway->list();
echo json_encode($users),PHP_EOL;

$userGateway->delete($id);
```

The code works all right for a simple CRUD but I'd like to know whether it can be improved or may be there are some critical faults I don't realize.

Comment: `list` can internally call `listBySql`

Comment: Man, I am totally blind! It was intended to be like that, but remained from the first prototype. I looked at this part many times and completely missed it!  Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: you can probably add type hints for params and return types on validate(), delete() and insert() methods. Also, class properties can have type hints too.

Comment: @user3402600 thank you, good catch! Indeed it's inconsistent and should be fixed

Answer (score 2):

- In `list()`, because `$page` is a single-use variable, I don't know that it is worth decrementing.  Perhaps write just one line as:

  ```
  $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
  ```

  but then again `$offset` is a single-use variable.  If you prefer the declarative coding style, leave it as is.  Alternatively, you could just write the arithmetic directly in the `execute()` call.  (either way, don't forget to add the space between `offset` and `limit` arguments)

  ```
  $stmt->execute([($page - 1) * $limit, $limit]);
  ```

  or because of precedence, you can pre-decrement to avoid parentheses:

  ```
  $stmt->execute([--$page * $limit, $limit]);
  ```

  or as stated in comments, *"list can internally call listBySql"* from @hjpotter92:

  ```
  public function list(int $page = 1, int $limit = 50): array
  {
      return listBySQL("SELECT * FROM `$this->table` LIMIT ?,?", [--$page * $limit, $limit]);
  }
  ```
- Please add the `int` type declaration to the `$id` argument in `read()`.  I think that `read()` can be reduced to this:

  ```
  return reset($this->listBySQL("SELECT * FROM `$this->table` WHERE `$this->primary`=?", [$id])) ?: null;
  ```

  because if `fetchAll()` delivers an empty array, then `reset()` will return `false` in which case the [Elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993455/2943403) can return the desired `null` value.  This is more of a style preference alternative rather than a functional gain -- the only real benefit is removing the `$ret` variable.
- I would prefer that `update()` return `int` instead of `void` (even if your demo doesn't seek this information).  In my projects, I always return the number of affected rows.  This is integral in knowing if the query was actually successful in making changes or if there were no changes from the valid query.  I find this to be as important as `insert()` returning the new id.
- Please add the `array` type declaration on `$data` in `insert()` and remove the blank line after returning the new id in `insert()`.
- Please add the `int` type declaration on `$id` in `delete()`.
- There is some inconsistency regarding when you declare a `$sql` variable and when you write the sql string directly into the `prepare()` call.  I think you should pick one style or the other.  My leanings, of course, bias toward removing single-use variables.
- `validate()`'s incoming argument should have an `array` type declaration.  The `implode()` call in the thrown exception could use some glue -- a comma at minimum.